# Search what if the nature of the limit

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I must find the limit $\ell$ defined bellow. I was wondering if $\ell<1$. This limit came from the following series: 
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{3^{n}}. $$
Let's call $$c_{n}=2^{n}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{3^{n}}$$
**What I did:** was to consider the quotient $$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}}$$ 
which gives
$$\ell = \underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}\ \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_{n}} =\underset{n\to \infty}{\lim}\ \frac{\displaystyle{2^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{n+2}}{3^{n+1}}}}{\displaystyle{2^{n}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{3^{n}}}}.$$

**after**:I multiply and  find $\ell<1$. But, I don't know if it is right.

> Can you please check if you find the same? I may have done something wrong..

Comment: Surely you've already cancelled the obvious factors of $2$ and $3$?

Comment: yes i have done it ,but  i want confirmation

Comment: Yes sorry,next time i will try better to give it to all to understand it

Comment: You will expedite the  process of getting a high quality, helpful Answer if you show the steps you followed, e.g. after cancelling the  $2$'s and $3$'s, what do we have left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the same; your approach seems fine to me.